# How can I add a reference to asp.net project (wcf or html page) in my c++ project

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, http

I'm working on a project which is composed of two parts:processing part-written in c++, and UI part-written in asp.net c#.
I made an http request from the c++ project to a page in the asp.net part.
the problem is that I don't know how to add a reference to the web project(a page in it) in my c++ project, so the c++ part could communicate with the c# part. http request will be executed well.

Do you know how I can make the c++ part know the asp.net page(something like add web reference in c#,but now I need that in c++).

I wrote the following code of the http request in c++:

```
 HINTERNET handle = InternetOpen("Upload", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,     
          NULL, NULL, 0);
if (handle)
{

    HINTERNET handleConnect = 
                    InternetConnect(handle, "localhost:4653/webservice.asmx", 
                             INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, 
                             INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, NULL, NULL);
    if (handleConnect)
    {
        if (HINTERNET handleOpenReq = 
                        HttpOpenRequest(handleConnect, TEXT("POST"), 
                               TEXT("/HelloWorld"), NULL, NULL, NULL, 
                               INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 0))
        {
            if (HttpSendRequest(handleOpenReq, NULL, 0, NULL 
                                             ,0))
                cout << "ddddd" << endl;
            else
            {
                DWORD p = GetLastError();
                int a = 9;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

but httpsendrequest returns 0. I think that's because I have no a reference to my asp.net project..am I right? if so, How could I add that?
thanks

Comment: Why you just can't do real http request to your web site in c++ and use response? Or you need to operate the whole `Page` object instance?

Comment: sorry, didn't understand your question.. what do you mean 'real http request'?

Comment: In your original question you are asking about reference. In terms of .Net reference is when one project directly uses code and objects from another. But in your case you just need to do HTTP request like you do in your example. So it doesn't actually related to .Net as there is no anything specific for .Net, and question is - how to make network request in c++. I'm not too familiar with that, so you would need to wait for other's answers.

Comment: thanks..appreciate your trying for helping me...

Comment: however, I would like to ask you again..isn't it like when I try to make a redirecting from one project to another in .net? while I would not have a reference from one to the other, it would not work,would it?